# Trying to find a Scifi comedy short about time travel / meeting yourself from the future

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I was full sure this was by the Invisible Engine guys but I've searched their Youtube and Vimeo feeds and can't find anything.

Plot in full:

A man is being stalked by a weirdo in a helmet. He goes through a doorway and waits around the corner for his stalker, then grabs and confronts him.

The stalker reveals he is the man's future self, and has come back in time to warn him about something, but basically he's so stoned he can't remember. He decides he must get a degree from Brown University. Then he asks him for some weed, and a loan of 5000 dollars. Then he pulls a gun on his past self. Past self tries to talk sense into him.

Suddenly a very old man appears in front of them. Future self shoots him, and it turns out he is the far, distant future version of both of them. He dies saying "in a way, I think, I've always known!"

Can anyone find this for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it!

[*I'm From The Future*](http://vimeo.com/14280638), written and directed by Chris Cantwell, who *is* one of the Invisible Engine crew, so I was right

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like "By His Bootstraps" by Heinlein, sort of.

Protagonist is met by a future copy, while drunkenly trying to finish a college paper.  Future copy tries to get him to come to the future, but second copy arrives to stop them.  Fist fight ensues, first guy gets knocked through the gate.  Older man sends him back to get himself forward...

Later, he borrows money to buy things to help him out, as he wants to replace the older man that he is now suspicious of.  He goes back 10 year.  He eventually realizes the old man was himself when his drunk first self plops through the gate 10 years later.

Comment: Well, I don't know if it was inspired by that or not, but this was not a Heinlein fan film. It was a comedy sketch.